# Postfix: set up outgoing server to server encryption

Tags: postfix, tls

I'm trying to configure postfix that it sends a mail encrypted with TLS to the recipient server.

What I have: receiving mails encrypted (other server -> my server) and users can connect encrypted to my server.

Server: Debian 7.2 with postfix 2.9.6

config lines:

/etc/postfix/main.conf (relevant codelines)

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

/etc/postfix/tls_policy (just for testing, I want it for all domains)

```
google.com encrypt
.google.com encrypt
gmail.com encrypt
.gmail.com encrypt
```

I tried some combinations of the above and even put it directly in the master.conf, but nothing works:

```
Dec 10 10:10:21 myserver postfix/smtp[7101]: 9019B4583500: to=<my.address@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.26]:25, delay=0.96, delays=0.13/0.01/0.27/0.55, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1386666621 u49si13392861eep.148 - gsmtp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set `smtp_tls_security_level` to a value other than `none` or `may` (what you have now).

Note that there are a lot of other factors playing into this, and you may need to set other values as well. See [postfix' TLS README.](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls)

Comment: Did that too (encrypt), postfix seems to just ignore it. What are the other factors? I can't see them, even after studying the readme.

Comment: This is different from you original question, since you now have a different setup to begin with. But as a hint nonetheless; make sure to rerun postmap and that the peer offers TLS at all. __But have you asserted that the mail is indeed transmitted in the clear?__ Note that TLS encryption for SMTP is _not_ dependent on the TCP port number.

Comment: Oh well, I just tcpdump'ed all. It was encrypted, but this was not logged. `smtp_tls_security_level = may` is sufficent btw. I see already the next problem, TlS connections are untrusted, but I'll look into it first.